# Should I combine interface implementations using reflection (C#)?

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I'll present a simplified case of my situation.

So, I'm making some transformations within `MyClass` type

```
public interface ITransformer
{
  List<MyClass> Transform(MyClass item);
}
```

Because the transformations are really different, it makes perfect sense to provide them as different implementations of `ITransformer`.

However, now there is a need to have a combined result of all possible transformations. Something like `GlobalTransformer : ITransformer` whose `Transform` method calls all other implementations and combines their results...

Does it make sense? Should I use reflection for it? Or should I approach the problem differently somehow?

Comment: @GrantWinney I showed the basic idea without context-specific clutter. And the way of combining implementations (in a list, using reflection or other) is what I'm trying to decide right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go that way:

```
public class GlobalTransformer : ITransformer
{
     private readonly IList<ITransformer> _availableTransformers;

     public GlobalTransformer(IList<ITransformer> availableTransformers)
     {
         _availableTransformers = _availableTransformers;
     }

     public List<MyClass> override Transform(MyClass item) {
        List<MyClass> result = new List<MyClass>();
        foreach (var item in _availableTransformers) {
           result.AddRange(item.Transform(item));
        }
        return result;
     }
}
```

I would then go one step forward and use `IoC` like `Autofac` or `SimpleInjector` to inject that list to your `GlobalTransformer` class

I also would strongly avoid reflection as it's slow.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot know all possible transformations. A project referencing your library could create it's own `ITransformer` implementation and you'd never know about it.

And even if you could: I doubt that you would even *want* to know about them: If you create a `TestTransformer` in your unit tests, would you really want to apply it blindly?

Instead, I'd manually track all transformer implementations - in the simplest case, you'd just use a `List<ITransformer>` containing one instance of each transformer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The provided thoughts are valid and very interesting. I ended up accepting other answer because it gives the prototype code of tracking `List<ITransformer>` which seems like a way to go in my situation.